# Cordova playing html5 video

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, video

I use cordova to build a hybrid signage application. I need to display a video on part of the screen when I try to display it then I don't see any video but sound. When I display video as fullscreen there is no problem. But I need to display it on part of the screen for example width: 400px height:400px top:100px left:100px

```html
<video 
id="videoContent_0" src="file:///storage/emulated/0/DS/MediaFiles/1004.mp4" autoplay="" style="z-index: 100; display: inline-block;">
</video>
```

Comment: I know my answer isn't good but i tried to provide you quick solution.

Comment: You can't directly reference a storage location in the `src` attribute with Cordova. If the video source was a network stream it should work. As mentioned below, a better solution would be to use a plugin to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution to use cordova plugin then you can achieve wanted result.

> Installation

```
cordova plugin add com.moust.cordova.videoplayer
```

> Using: Just call the play method with a video file path as argument. The video player will close itself when the video will be completed.

```
VideoPlayer.play(
    "file:///android_asset/www/movie.mp4",
    {
        volume: 0.5,
        scalingMode: VideoPlayer.SCALING_MODE.SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
    },
    function () {
        console.log("video completed");
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```